# How to detect if my ball body has hit another static body

Tags: javascript, matter.js

So I have created two bodies in my world, a ball and a flat surface. Due to gravity the ball drops onto the surface and collides with it.

I thought I was on the right track using `Events` and `Body.isSensor()` but I can't seem to get from my event listener which bodies have collied i.e. the body name.

**sketch.js**

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Events = Matter.Events;

var engine = Engine.create();

var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

var surface = Bodies.rectangle(250, 250, 400, 100, { isStatic: true });

var ball = Bodies.circle(200, 0, 11, {
      density: 0.05,
      restitution: 0.7,
      inertia: Infinity
  });

 Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
    console.log('collisionStart');
    var pairs = event.pairs;
    console.log(pairs);
  });

World.add(engine.world, [surface, ball]);
Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

The event is triggered however there is nothing in the pairs variable. What am I doing wrong?

Also when I turn the `isSensor: true` on, the ball appears to travel through the static body.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qk3yLfyq/12/

Comment: Haven't worked with ``matter.js``, but from logging ``event`` I see that ``event.source.pairs`` is an object that contains information about the bodies and collision status. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think it is but I'm not sure it was supposed to be there!

Comment: Yeah, ``event.pairs`` also existed, but as you said it was just an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path and are getting the event object and working with it,  you just need to parse some more info. Try this for example, replace

```
Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
console.log('collisionStart');
var pairs = event.pairs;
console.log(pairs);
});
```

with

```
Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
    event.pairs.forEach(function(obj){
      console.log('BodyA is static: ' + obj.bodyA.isStatic + '. BodyB is static: ' + obj.bodyB.isStatic)
    })
  });
```

in the latter scenario I'm just parsing a bit more info from the object being returned by that event.

Comment: Yes I have managed to do this as per the comment on my question. However why is `event.source.pairs` been populated and `event.pairs`is not?

Comment: It is being populated, in my code I used event.pairs. Pairs is an array, and I'm iterating over it using the forEach function to check and log event.pairs[0] or whatever's bodyA.isStatic and bodyB.isStatic properties.

Comment: Not in my test case, see my jsfiddle. event.pairs is an empty array. Array(0)

Comment: it's not returning an empty array, probably just logging it that way. Try logging pairs.length or pairs[0] instead of pairs and you'll see what I mean

Comment: I got that working, so I don't need to use the `isSensor` at all for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I was using the `collisionActive` event, which wasn't firing. When I switched to `collisionStart` there were events.